# I cannot compile the Arduino sketch when I remove the void loop function?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, motor, arduino-motor-shield

```
#include <AFMotor.h> 

AF_DCMotor motor(2,MOTOR12_64KHZ); 

void movefor ();

void moveback();


    void setup() 

    {



    Serial.begin(9600); 

    Serial.println("Motor test!");` `motor.setSpeed(200); 

    movefor ();
    moveback ();
    }

        void movefor( ){
        motor.run(FORWARD); 
    delay(1000); 
    motor.run(RELEASE); 
     delay(100);
    }

    void moveback( ) {
      motor.run(BACKWARD);
    delay(1000);  
    motor.run(RELEASE); 
     delay(100);
    }
```

While trying to compile this the error message is *error compiling for board Arduino Uno*

I want the functions outside loop so removed it.

Even if I keep void loop and leave it blank then my motors will like run forward, backward and forward afterwards continuously .

Comment: you get an linker error because the main function in core main.c calls the loop() function. it must exist.

Comment: Error is " cannot compile for the board Arduino Uno"

Comment: turn on verbose mode in Preferences

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and shouldn't, remove the loop function. Arduino sketches must have a setup function and a loop function. The setup function is called once and the loop function is called repeatedly.

Just make your loop function look like this:

```
void loop() {
    movefor ();
    moveback ();
}
```

Your motor will move forward, then move backwards, forever.

Note that you should read up on how to avoid using the delay function. You really need to use `millis()` to do your timing rather than delays. Do an internet search on "Arduino blink no delay." That's basic Arduino programming.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong within the motor, circuit or the motor class.

What happens is when you use a setup and loop is the following:

```
setup();
while (1) { loop(); }
```

So the loop function is executed forever, if it is empty, nothing will happen. If you say that the motor runs forward, it is probably because of a wrong implementation of the motor class.

Arduino IDE dictates there is always a loop, and having an empty loop is the same as having no loop at all.

What you can try is:

- In the setup, only execute movefor() and check what happens
- Than only execute moveback() and check what happens
- Than make combinations and see if the problem is inside movefor or moveback

For the first steps you can add a delay to easier see if there is a side effect.

Comment: I have tried what you said and code is working good  . I want forward motion then backward.   After this I want the same to be continuously moving forward and backward. But the problem that occurs is that it will always move forward after 1 forward and backward motion.  I think the loop is being continuously called and that is disturbing that's why I want to remove the loop. Maybe the  problem is in header file but how can I check this file?

Comment: you should get what you want when adding in setup: while(1) { movefor(); moveback(); } but I doubt that will work either. The header file can be found where you installed the library, you always can do a file search on your PC (crude way but it works; I don't know by head where the libraries are stored).

Comment: I have the AFMotor library in Documents-Arduino-libraries-AFMotor , everything looks fine here